# IE table border bug - OK on Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table

everyone,

I have designed a quick html doc that will be incorporated in Outlook (hence the need to have inline styles inside the HTML). Everything is looking fine on Chrome and on Safari, but IE11 is showing the below problem. The table border is messed up, like it has two colours inside it, instead of only one, like the good version on Chrome. Also, Firefox seems to be ignoring the table set for the colour and showing a beveled version of it... Does anyone have an idea about this? I'm pasting example image and my code below.

[image depicting bug in IE against good version on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwezl.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Xmas Card</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 60px 300px 60px 300px; background-color:#d2d2d1">
<table>
 <tr>
 <div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:20px">
  <span style="font-family:sans-serif; font-size:10pt"><a href="#">If you have problems opening this message, read online here</a></span>
  </div>
 </tr>
</table>
 <table border="8" rules="none" bordercolor="#8a7e70" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="600px">
  <tr style="background-color:#ffffff" align="center">
   <td>
    <img src="#" alt="corners top">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#ffffff" align="center">
   <td>
   <img src="#" alt="logo">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#ffffff" align="center">
   <td>
   <h1 style="font-size:24pt; font-family:sans-serif; color:#aa212f; text-align:center">Season's Greetings</h1> 
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#ffffff" align="center">
   <td>
   <img src="#" alt="Xmas branches">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#ffffff" align="center">
   <td>
    <a href="#"><img src="/#" alt="button"></a>
   </td>
  </tr>
   <tr style="background-color:#ffffff" align="center">
   <td>
    <img src="#" alt="corners bottom">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you so much for your kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to set the table's border attribute, you should keep in mind that the border-style is required. 
The definition and usage of CSS border you could refer to the following W3C document:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp

I suggest that you could set the border-color, border-style and border-width separately like:

```
<table style="border-color: #8a7e70; border-style: solid; border-width:8px;" rules="none" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="600">...</table>
```

Or you could write three attributes together:

```
<table style="border:8px solid #8a7e70;" rules="none" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="600">...</table>
```

[the running result in Chrome and IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5UjW.png)